# Bind URI parameter in SQLite with Ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite, prepared-statement

I want to store the URL of a webpage on my database using the following code:

```
def add_page(database, url, title)
  sql = "insert into paginas(url, titulo) values(:url, :titulo)"
  database.execute(sql, "url" => url, "titulo" => title)
end
```

But I get this error:

```
/home/cris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:39:in `bind_param': can't prepare URI::HTTP (RuntimeError)
```

Any way to solve this problem?

PS: the following code works properly:

```
def add_page(database, url, title)
  sql = "insert into paginas(url, titulo) values('#{url}', '#{title}')"
  database.execute(sql)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that the SQLite driver doesn't know how to convert a `URI::HTTP` to an SQLite-native type. You can help it along by converting the URI back to a String:

```
database.execute(sql, "url" => url.to_s, "titulo" => title)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Also explains why the second snippet of code worked properly.